# Inverse operator representation in second quantization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-optics

Distance operator r can be represented as a sum of a and a+ operators. (Annihilation and creation operators respectively). In the same way, is it possible to represent 1/r?

Basically, I want to write Coulomb interaction between two charges. This interaction term has 1/r. Is my approach correct?

I am new to second quantization.

Comment: Do you mean $r$ or $x$?

Comment: It is $r$. If the vector position of charge 1 is $\vec{r}_2$ and that of charge 2 is $\vec{r}_{2}$, then $r=|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2|$. So I need the operator form of $r^{-1}$. Does such a form exist?

Comment: Well the problem is that I don’t know how you can write $r$ as a polynomial function of $a$ and $a^\dagger$, which are expressed in terms of $x$ and $p_x$ (or $y$ and $p_y$ etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are two spatially separated charged particle densities $\Omega(\vec{r_1})$ and $\Omega(\vec{r_2})$ then the interaction energy is given by: $$ E_{int}=\int{d\vec{r_1}d\vec{r_2}}V(|\vec{r_1}-\vec{r_2}|)\Omega(\vec{r_1})\Omega(\vec{r_2})$$
where $V(|\vec{r_1}-\vec{r_2}|)$ is interaction poterntial between two particles: $$V(|\vec{r_1}-\vec{r_2}|)=q^2/|\vec{r_1}-\vec{r_2}|$$
In second quantization  $\Omega(\vec{r})$ is $a^{\dagger}(\vec{r})a(\vec{r})$.

Therefore the interaction Hamiltonian in second quantization is, $$H_{int}=\int{d\vec{r_1}d\vec{r_2}}V(|\vec{r_1}-\vec{r_2}|)a^{\dagger}(\vec{r_1})a(\vec{r_1})a^{\dagger}(\vec{r_2})a(\vec{r_2})$$

Most people prefer to write the above equation in a bit different way that creation operators come first and annihilation operators come second. These two representations are differed by a constant and it is normally omitted. So the new representation is:$$H_{int}=\int{d\vec{r_1}d\vec{r_2}}V(|\vec{r_1}-\vec{r_2}|)a^{\dagger}(\vec{r_1})a^{\dagger}(\vec{r_2})a(\vec{r_1})a(\vec{r_2})$$

Comment: It is funny to see that my question/answer is getting downvotes from 'reputed' users probably because I didn't consider their answers. I got -2 reputations after posting my answer (source from Michigan University: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~sunkai/teaching/Fall_2015/9_10_2015.pdf) to my question. Funny people!!!

Answer (score 1):

The notion that one can represent an operator for the spatial degrees of freedom as the sums and differences of creation and annihilation operators is a common misconception. It comes from the *analogy* of the harmonic oscillator that we use to formulate second quantization. Although a physical harmonic oscillator involves spatial displacements and momentum, the same is not true for a field that we wish to quantize. For the quantized field, the annihilation and creation operator *only* address the particle number degrees of freedom.

To incorporate spatial degrees of freedom, one needs a whole set of different creation and annihilation operators, one for each spatial mode. Usually these modes are the plane waves and therefore the annihilation and reation operators are distinguished by the wave vectors, as in $a({\bf k}),a^{\dagger}({\bf k})$.

If you want to know how to use this to formulate the Coulomb interaction, I suggest you read up on quantum electrodynamics. It is quite a mouth full.

Comment: If the Coulomb interaction is between two pinned charges, then wavevector need not be taken care of. Right? And, the creation of a charge at position $\vec{r}$ can be represented by $a^{\dagger} (\vec{r})$. Right?

Comment: When you make it a function of position, then you actually have the field operator, which can be expressed in terms of the creation operators, which depend on the wave vectors.

Comment: I don't understand how wave vector dependency comes for a creation/annihilation operator for a stationary (pinned) particle. It has zero kinetic energy. I have seen some scientific journal articles wherein they didn't consider $\vec{k}$ when they wrote these operators.

Comment: Perhaps, it can help to remember that when you fix the position, you have an infinite incertainty in the momentum. In QFT, one would basically compute the two-point function to find the Green function or propagator that connects two points. This will then tell you how the force between two charges would work. In the process you would need to resolve the field operators at the two points in terms of the plane waves.

Comment: It is true that a static particle can be represented as a sum of plane waves of momentum from -inf to +inf. But that is just a Fourier definition of the same information that a particle is static. Even if we represent a static particle in its Fourier definition, we're gonna need infinite annihilation and creation operators (Each corresponds to a particular momentum). Why don't we simply represent it in spatial dimensions?

Comment: To get from one point to the other, one needs the dinamics, whih is usually expressed as a differential operator. To turn this into a function, which is given by the Green function (or propagator) one usually expresses in in terms of the Fourier domain.

Comment: Please note that the original question is not asking about any dynamics of particles. It simply asks about the Coulomb interaction between two static particles. As I mentioned earlier you may express this interaction in Fourier domain. But that is like making things complex (in this case only) as this can be completely dealt with operators which create particles at some position $\vec{r}$. For more information please read the link given in the comment of the accepted answer. Please do any further commenting only after reading it. Thanks!